# Stringify and Parse Mult-dimensional Array Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, multidimensional-array

```js
var data = [{
    id: "Calligraphy",
    category: "artsAndCrafts",
    categoryName: "Arts & Crafts",
    place: "indoor",
    activity: "light",
    difficulty: "medium",
    link:"tennis.html",
    description:"Knitting is great"
}, {
    id: "Cross-stitching",
    category: "artsAndCrafts",
    categoryName: "Arts & Crafts",
    place: "indoor",
    activity: "light",
    difficulty: "easy",
    link:"knitting.html",
    description:"Knitting is great"
}, {
    id: "Gardening",
    category: "artsAndCrafts",
    categoryName: "Arts & Crafts",
    place: "outdoor",
    activity: "light",
    difficulty: "easy",
    link:"knitting.html",
    description:"Knitting is great"
}];

var myHobbies = [
];




    //Alphabetical Order
        function compareStrings(a, b) {
              a = a.toLowerCase();
              b = b.toLowerCase();

          return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
        }

        data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return compareStrings(a.id, b.id);
        })

        var myHobbies = new Array();
        
        //Show hobbies on explore
        function loadHobbies(){
            myHobbies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedHobbies"));
            $("#indvSports").empty();
            $("#subheader").html("<h2>Explore</h2><div id='searchMenu'><form method='get' action='input' id='searchbox' action=''><input id='formInput' type='text' placeholder='search'></form><input type='image' id='submit' onclick='search()' src='img/search.png' alt='Submit'/><img id='menuButton' src='img/menu.png'></div>");
            
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#buttons").append("<a href='#' class='block' id='data[i].id' onclick='loadPage("+i+")'>" + data[i].id + "</a>");
            }
        }
        window.onload = loadHobbies();
        
        //Show and Hide Menu
        var menu = $('#menu'), but = $('#menuButton');
        menu.hide();
$(document).on('click', '*', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); //<-- stop the event propagating to ancestral elements
    if ($(this).is(but))   //<-- on button click, toggle visibility of menu
        menu.toggle();
    else if (!$(this).closest(menu).length) //<-- on click outside, hide menu
        menu.hide();
});
        
        //Sift and display categories
        function categorySift(id) {
            menu.hide();
            $('#buttons').empty();
            var categoryId = id;
            
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].category == categoryId) {
                    $("#buttons").append("<a href='#' class='block' id='data[i].id' onclick='loadPage("+i+")'>" + data[i].id + "</a>");
               }
            }
        }
        
        //Sift and display categories for indoor/outdoor
        function categorySiftPlace(id) {
            menu.hide();
            var categoryId = id;
            
            $('#buttons').empty();
            
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].place == categoryId) {
                    $("#buttons").append("<a href='#' class='block' id='data[i].id' onclick='loadPage("+i+")'>" + data[i].id + "</a>");
               }
            }
        }
        
        //Search
        function search(){
            var formInput = document.getElementById("formInput").value.toLowerCase();
            var count = 0;
            
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].id.toLowerCase() == formInput) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    $("#buttons").html("<p id='results'>"+count+" results found for '" + formInput + "'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=''> X</a></p><a href='#' class='block' id='data[i].id' onclick='loadPage("+i+")'>" + data[i].id + "</a>");
                    break;
               }
                else{
                    $('#buttons').html("<p id='noResults'>No results found for '" + formInput + "'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=''> X</a></p>");
                }
            }        
            document.getElementById("formInput").value='';
        }
        
        //Individual pages
        function loadPage(which) {
            currentI = which;
            $('#buttons').empty();
            $("#myHobbiesSection").empty();
            $("#subheader").html("<style>#subheader{height:60px;}</style><h2><b>"+data[which].id+"</b><br>"+ data[which].categoryName +"</h2><a href='index.html'><img src='img/back.png' id='backButton'/></a><img src='img/add.png' onclick='addHobby("+currentI+")' id='addButton'/>");
            $("#indvSports").html("<p>"+data[which].description+"</p>");
        }
        
        //Individual pages(from My Hobbies page)
        function loadPageMyHobby(which) {
            currentI = which;
            $('#buttons').empty();
            $("#myHobbiesSection").empty();
            $("#subheader").html("<style>#subheader{height:60px;}</style><h2><b>"+myHobbies[which].id+"</b><br>"+ myHobbies[which].categoryName +"</h2><a href='index.html'><img src='img/back.png' id='backButton'/></a><img src='img/add.png' onclick='addHobby("+currentI+")' id='addButton'/>");
            $("#indvSports").html("<p>"+myHobbies[which].description+"</p>");
        }
        
        
        //Add hobby
        function addHobby(which) {
            alert("Would you like to add "+ data[which].id.toLowerCase() +" to your hobbies?");
            myHobbies.push({id: data[which].id, categoryName: data[which].categoryName, description: data[which].description});
            
            localStorage.setItem("savedHobbies", JSON.stringify(myHobbies));
            alert("done");
            
        }
        
        //<a href='#' onclick='editMyHobby' id='editButton'>Edit</a>
        
        
        //My Hobbies Page
        function myHobbiesPage(){
            $("#myHobbiesSection").empty();
            
            myHobbies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedHobbies"));
            
            $("#subheader").html("<style>#subheader{height:30px;}</style><h2>My Hobbies</h2>");
            $('#buttons').empty();
            $("#indvSports").empty();
            for (i = 0; i < myHobbies.length; i++) {
                $("#myHobbiesSection").append("<a href='#' class='blockMyHobbies' id='myHobbies[i].id' onclick='loadPageMyHobby("+i+")'>" + myHobbies[i].id + "</a><a href='#' id='deleteButton' onclick='deleteHobby("+i+")'>X</a>");
            }
        }
        
        
        //Lets you edit on My Hobby
//        function deleteHobby(i){
//            alert(myHobbies[i].id);
//            delete myHobbies[i];
//            
//            localStorage.setItem("savedHobbies", JSON.stringify(myHobbies));
//        }
```

Hello,
I'm making an app that contains a multi-dimensional array that must be stored into local storage. I'm trying to get it to take elements from the main array `data` and store them in `myHobbies`.

I can see in the last function that when I replace the `myHobbies[i].id` snippet with `data[i].id`, it shows the elements (with the wrong information because it's the wrong array), but this shows that the array `myHobbies` is storing new elements when you tell it to.

I think the problem is that it's not parsing them correctly or something along those lines. It could also be the variables where the parsed array is stored (I'm a little confused in that area). If anyone knows what I could be doing wrong, that would be great.

Comment: Please try to reduce your problem to the [**minimum**, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [This demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bL29h8v7/) shows your code working when I add some function calls. What doesn't work? Are the items not showing up on the page? The parsing shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yeah with my current code, the page that calls the myHobbiesPage() function doesn't show anything. With a test alert at the end of the function, it doesn't show up. It's like any time I try to display something with the myHobbies array like I did in that function, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any errors in your developer console?

Comment: It says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" for the line inside the for loop of the final function.

Comment: I noticed on your earlier code, in a function that was commented out, you seemed to be removing an item from the array using `delete`, if I remember correctly. Not sure if that plays into the issue here, but that's not the right way to delete an item because it leaves a hole in the Array. You should use `.splice()` instead. As to this issue, while keeping it minimal, you'll need to add some more info because there's nothing wrong with your current code.

Comment: Yeah, I did use delete, and realized later I should've used splice. The code actually stopped working when I tried the code with the delete in it. Despite any undos or anything it never went back to working properly like it had before. I even tried renaming the array just to see if it would work but it seemed to have vanished.

Comment: Is the script external to the page? If so, an old version could be cached in the browser. I'm tinkering with your original code right now to see what it could be.

Comment: ...just tested the full code you originally posted, and it works. In your developer tools, there should be an option to disable the cache when the dev tools are open. Can't tell much else from here.

Comment: Oh, yes. The arrays are in a different js file. All the functions are in the index html file. Should I change that or just clear the cache?

Comment: Yeah, clear the cache, and set up the dev tools as I described above.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to clear it and disable it, but it still didn't work. Didn't work in a different browser either. Same error messages. Firefox says "TypeError: myHobbies is null.
myHobbiesPage()
onclick()"

Comment: Make sure `myHobbies` is declared in a scope where `myHobbiesPage()` can reach it. Since `myHobbiesPage()` must be a global function (because you're calling it from HTML), then `myHobbies` must also be global.

Comment: I tried declaring myHobbies[] before everything outside of all the functions, and still the same error. Does it have anything to do with the fact that the parsed array is being stored into a duplicate array of the same name? (The one that's declared with var myHobbies = new Array();) That part confuses me, but I tried creating a new array of a different name and it still didn't work. But all of this was as it was when it worked before, so I'm not sure where the problem could lie.

Comment: Another strange thing is that the "done" alert in the addHobby() function is showing up in chrome(the main browser I've been using), but not in firefox. I tried moving the alert above everything in the addHobby() function and it finally worked in Firefox. I'm not sure why it works in Chrome but not Firefox, but there may be something not working in that function.

Comment: It shouldn't matter about the array storage. Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net demo of the issue? That may make it easier for me to help. If you do, be mindful of the settings in the `javascript` menu. And be sure to only include the minimal code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ftup37h3/#&togetherjs=NuJMBNv4eh   -I'm not sure if this will show anything, because for some reason it's not working for me.

Comment: Under the `javascript` menu, you had `onLoad` selected, which means the code is wrapped in a function, so the array isn't global. It should be changed to `no wrap- in <head>`. Also, I selected a jQuery version from the menu.

Comment: ...one issue was that `window.onload = loadHobbies();` should not have the `()` at the end. The function needs to be assigned, not invoked.

Comment: ...in a couple spots, you didn't declare the `i` variable with `var`. Probably not an issue here, but always a good idea.

Comment: When I click to call `myHobbiesPage()` it works. Not for you?

Comment: I changed it so that it adds things into an array of a different name and it works! Only problem now is that it will only store one at a time and replaces it. I'll update the jsfiddle to my new code so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Do you have anything else with the name `myHobbies`? A function or something? Maybe an element with that ID?

Comment: Did a search and looks like no ids or anything. Just used as the array and when it's called.

Comment: Odd. It worked for me with the original name in the jsFiddle.

Comment: If you don't bind your event handler in HTML, you won't need to rely on global functions, and therefore global variables. Having global variable collision is often an issue.

Comment: I've got to break way for now. I'll check back tomorrow to see if you figured it out. Good luck!

Comment: I finally got it, Thank you!

Comment: @BaileyMiller: Good, glad to hear it.